# Unknown symbol in module, or unknown parameter / Unknown symbol usb_hcd_amd_remote_wakeup_quirk (err -2)

Tags: drivers, usb, kernel, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm trying to make USB modules_install and make install them inside my WSL2 running with ubuntu 18.04 (tried also with ubuntu 20) and the kernel 4.19.104,but it didn't work :

```
ziomarietto@DESKTOP-N9UN2H3:/mnt/c/Users/marietto2020/Desktop/WSL/WSL/Ubuntu-KVM/4.19.104/WSL2-Linux-Kernel-4.19.104-microsoft-standard$ sudo make modules_install -j 12

[sudo] password for ziomarietto:

INSTALL drivers/hid/hid-generic.ko
INSTALL drivers/hid/hid.ko
INSTALL drivers/hid/usbhid/usbhid.ko
INSTALL drivers/net/mii.ko
INSTALL drivers/net/phy/libphy.ko
INSTALL drivers/net/usb/asix.ko
INSTALL drivers/net/usb/ax88179_178a.ko
INSTALL drivers/net/usb/cdc_ether.ko
INSTALL drivers/net/usb/cdc_ncm.ko
INSTALL drivers/net/usb/cdc_subset.ko
INSTALL drivers/net/usb/net1080.ko
INSTALL drivers/net/usb/rndis_host.ko
INSTALL drivers/net/usb/usbnet.ko
INSTALL drivers/net/usb/zaurus.ko
INSTALL drivers/usb/class/cdc-acm.ko
INSTALL drivers/usb/common/usb-common.ko
INSTALL drivers/usb/core/usbcore.ko
INSTALL drivers/usb/phy/phy-generic.ko
INSTALL drivers/usb/serial/ftdi_sio.ko
INSTALL drivers/usb/serial/usbserial.ko
INSTALL drivers/usb/storage/usb-storage.ko
INSTALL drivers/usb/usbip/usbip-core.ko
INSTALL drivers/usb/usbip/vhci-hcd.ko
DEPMOD 4.19.104-microsoft-standard
```

ziomarietto@DESKTOP-N9UN2H3:/mnt/c/Users/marietto2020/Desktop/WSL/WSL/Ubuntu-KVM/4.19.104/WSL2-Linux-Kernel-4.19.104-microsoft-standard$ sudo make install

```
sh ./arch/x86/boot/install.sh 4.19.104-microsoft-standard arch/x86/boot/bzImage
System.map "/boot"
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/apt-auto-removal 4.19.104-microsoft-standard /boot/vmlinuz-4.19.104-microsoft-standard
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools 4.19.104-microsoft-standard /boot/vmlinuz-4.19.104-microsoft-standard
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.19.104-microsoft-standard

W: mkconf: MD subsystem is not loaded, thus I cannot scan for arrays.
W: mdadm: failed to auto-generate temporary mdadm.conf file.

run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/pm-utils 4.19.104-microsoft-standard /boot/vmlinuz-4.19.104-microsoft-standard
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/unattended-upgrades 4.19.104-microsoft-standard /boot/vmlinuz-4.19.104-microsoft-standard
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/update-notifier 4.19.104-microsoft-standard /boot/vmlinuz-4.19.104-microsoft-standard

root@DESKTOP-N9UN2H3:/mnt/c/Users/marietto2020/Desktop/WSL/WSL/Ubuntu-KVM/4.19.104/WSL2-Linux-Kernel-4.19.104-microsoft-standard# modprobe usbcore
modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'usbcore': Unknown symbol in module, or unknown parameter (see dmesg)

[ 49.155158] hv_balloon: Max. dynamic memory size: 26100 MB
[ 907.557942] WSL2: Performing memory compaction.
[ 1809.551238] usbcore: Unknown symbol usb_hcd_amd_remote_wakeup_quirk (err -2)

root@DESKTOP-N9UN2H3:/mnt/c/Users/marietto2020/Desktop/WSL/WSL/Ubuntu-KVM/4.19.104/WSL2-Linux-Kernel-4.19.104-microsoft-standard# sudo modprobe usb-common

root@DESKTOP-N9UN2H3:/mnt/c/Users/marietto2020/Desktop/WSL/WSL/Ubuntu-KVM/4.19.104/WSL2-Linux-Kernel-4.19.104-microsoft-standard# sudo modprobe hid-generic

root@DESKTOP-N9UN2H3:/mnt/c/Users/marietto2020/Desktop/WSL/WSL/Ubuntu-KVM/4.19.104/WSL2-Linux-Kernel-4.19.104-microsoft-standard# sudo modprobe hid

root@DESKTOP-N9UN2H3:/mnt/c/Users/marietto2020/Desktop/WSL/WSL/Ubuntu-KVM/4.19.104/WSL2-Linux-Kernel-4.19.104-microsoft-standard# sudo modprobe usbnet
modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'usbnet': Unknown symbol in module, or unknown parameter (see dmesg)

root@DESKTOP-N9UN2H3:/mnt/c/Users/marietto2020/Desktop/WSL/WSL/Ubuntu-KVM/4.19.104/WSL2-Linux-Kernel-4.19.104-microsoft-standard# modprobe cdc_ether
modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'cdc_ether': Unknown symbol in module, or unknown parameter (see dmesg)

root@DESKTOP-N9UN2H3:/mnt/c/Users/marietto2020/Desktop/WSL/WSL/Ubuntu-KVM/4.19.104/WSL2-Linux-Kernel-4.19.104-microsoft-standard# modprobe rndis_host
modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'rndis_host': Unknown symbol in module, or unknown parameter (see dmesg)

root@DESKTOP-N9UN2H3:/mnt/c/Users/marietto2020/Desktop/WSL/WSL/Ubuntu-KVM/4.19.104/WSL2-Linux-Kernel-4.19.104-microsoft-standard# modprobe usbserial
modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'usbserial': Unknown symbol in module, or unknown parameter (see dmesg)

root@DESKTOP-N9UN2H3:/mnt/c/Users/marietto2020/Desktop/WSL/WSL/Ubuntu-KVM/4.19.104/WSL2-Linux-Kernel-4.19.104-microsoft-standard# modprobe usb-storage
modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'usb_storage': Unknown symbol in module, or unknown parameter (see dmesg)

root@DESKTOP-N9UN2H3:/mnt/c/Users/marietto2020/Desktop/WSL/WSL/Ubuntu-KVM/4.19.104/WSL2-Linux-Kernel-4.19.104-microsoft-standard# modprobe cdc-acm
modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'cdc_acm': Unknown symbol in module, or unknown parameter (see dmesg)

root@DESKTOP-N9UN2H3:/mnt/c/Users/marietto2020/Desktop/WSL/WSL/Ubuntu-KVM/4.19.104/WSL2-Linux-Kernel-4.19.104-microsoft-standard# modprobe ftdi_sio
modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'ftdi_sio': Unknown symbol in module, or unknown parameter (see dmesg)

root@DESKTOP-N9UN2H3:/mnt/c/Users/marietto2020/Desktop/WSL/WSL/Ubuntu-KVM/4.19.104/WSL2-Linux-Kernel-4.19.104-microsoft-standard# modprobe usbip-core

root@DESKTOP-N9UN2H3:/mnt/c/Users/marietto2020/Desktop/WSL/WSL/Ubuntu-KVM/4.19.104/WSL2-Linux-Kernel-4.19.104-microsoft-standard# modprobe vhci-hcd
modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'vhci_hcd': Unknown symbol in module, or unknown parameter (see dmesg)
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is months later, but I didn't find a good answer.

WSL2 will not boot your custom kernel by default.  It will load the default that came with your Windows distribution unless you explicitly configure it to load your custom kernel.

Check your running kernel compilation date by running

```
uname -v
```

If it is not the date you compiled your kernel, you need to copy it from /boot to your Windows filesystem and create a .wslconfig file in your C:\Users<USERNAME> folder with the following content

```
[wsl2]
kernel=c:\\users\\YOUR_USERNAME\\vmlinuz-4.19.128-microsoft-standard
```